# accessing static method within class variable

Tags: php, oop, stripe-payments

I have been looking around attempting to find out how to access a stripe static method within my own class. Essentially extending the stripe library.

Within Stripes Documentation the code would look like this:

```
\Stripe\Customer::create();
```

The code I am attempting to access from the stripe library:

```
public static function create($params = null, $opts = null)
{
    return self::_create($params, $opts);
}
```

Current top of file:

```
use Stripe\Charge;
use Stripe\Stripe;
use Stripe\Customer;
/**
 * Handles all stripe specific options
 */
class _Stripe
{
    protected $charge;
    protected $stripe;
    protected $customer;
    /**
     * Init Stripe Charge
     */
    public function init_charge()
    {
        $this->charge = new Charge;
    }
    /**
     * Init Stripe Class
     */
    public function init_stripe()
    {
        $this->stripe = new Stripe;
    }
    /**
     * Init Stripe Customer
     */
    public function init_customer()
    {
        $this->customer = new Customer;
    }
```

So far I have this:

```
$this->customer = new Customer;
$this->customer::create();
```

which is considered invalid syntax. Is there any possible way for me to do this within my own class?

Things I have tried:

```
{$this->customer}::create();
    Got: Unexpected '}'
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Within stripe, they are all static.

Comment: eliminate the ambiguity: `{$this->customer}::charge();`

Comment: but still you can not do $this->customer::charge();  .

Comment: I don't extend it. I Just initiate it. I added the top of my file. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is possible in PHP7 ( i don't sure about other versions ):

```
<?php

class Test
{
    public static $var1 = "something";

    public static function charge()
    {
        return self::$var1;
    }
}

$Object = new Test();
echo $Object->charge(); // Output: something
```

---

As you updated your question, i simulated with your structure and the below code works on PHP 7.0.5-3:

```
<?php

namespace Stripe;

class Customer
{
    public static function create($params = null, $opts = null)
    {
        return self::_create($params, $opts);
    }

    public static function _create($params, $opts)
    {
        return 'bla bla';
    }
}

// ...
use Stripe\Customer;

$Customer = new Customer();
echo $Customer->create(null, null); // Output: bla bla

// ...

class OtherClass
{
    public $instance;

    public function run()
    {
        $this->instance = new Customer();
        echo $this->instance->create(null, null);
    }
}

(new OtherClass)->run();
```

Comment: Well, in php7 you should be able to call it like $this->customer->create();, sorry i have no idea about 5.6

Comment: Ill attempt to do it in 5.6 I'll let you know.

Comment: Well, I thought you had to use `::` for static methods. I guess I was wrong. Thank you.